# req.files is undefined when uploading file with multer

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, multer

I am trying to build a Node.js Application in Express.js 4 that uploads an image. I decided to use the `multer` module but cannot access the uploaded file through `req.files`.
Here Is the code I am using. I restricted it to those parts that I believe are relevant.

Jade code:

```
form(method="POST", action="createPost", enctype="multipart/form-data")
        input(type="file", name="photo")
        br
        input(type="submit" value="upload")
```

in routes/admin.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var multer = require('multer');
var router = express.Router();
var upload = multer({dest: './uploads/'});

router.post('/createPost', upload.single('photo'), function(req, res, next) {
    console.log('files:', req.files);
    console.log('body:', req.body);
    // more code
}
```

output:

```
files: undefined
body: {}
```

The file is stored in the `uploads` folder but I cannot access its information in `req.files`. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When using `upload.single()`, per the multer documentation, the resulting file should be in `req.file`, not `req.files`.  See the example [in their doc here](https://github.com/expressjs/multer).

```
app.post('/profile', upload.single('avatar'), function (req, res, next) {
  // req.file is the `avatar` file
  // req.body will hold the text fields, if there were any
})
```

---

And, here's the actual doc for `upload.single()`:

> **.single(fieldname)**
>
> Accept a single file with the name fieldname. The single file will be
>   stored in req.file.